# R Library for computing cepstral coefficients from Auto-Correlation coefficients

Tags: r, linear-model, autocorrelation, regression-coefficients

My main goal is to compute [cepstral coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mel-frequency_cepstrum) in R from an ACF vector (Auto-Correlation function vector with discrete time-step). Correct me if I am wrong in terminology or whatever as I am not a statistician/signal-processor. My first question will be

- Are the elements of an ACF vector i.e. the auto-correlation-coefficients (ACC) linear-predictive-coefficients (LPC)? I think they are since an AR(p) process is a linear predictive model.

If my above hypothesis is true, then I have found MatLab code for converting LPC coefficients to cepstral coefficients (CC): [MatLab Code](http://www.mathworks.com/help/dsp/ref/lpctofromcepstralcoefficients.html). Then my question would reduce to:

- Is there an R library which will convert LPCs to CCs?

Please correct my terminology if I am wrong!